# Python Regex : match everything until certain character sequence

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture all data from a string until a certain character is hit. I think I have to do a negative look forward but can't seem to get it working.

The example string is

```
\"chn000000 | Kaiser Sorche | Guatemala \"
```

The regex I have come up with

```
\\"(?!\\
```

The value I want once matched:

```
chn000000 | Kaiser Soze | Guatemala
```

The start of the regex is working but can't get the rest work quite right. I want to capture everything until the `"\` sequence because the string in between might be different. Should I not be using a negative look forward?

Comment: *capture everything until the* ``"\``, that does not look coherent with your string

Comment: This: `(?<=\\").*?(?=\\")`? Demo: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vH9aP1/1)

Comment: You want to get everything between both "\?

Comment: If you're just trying to get rid of the ' \" ' then why not just do a simple string replace instead of a heavy regex capture? i.e.: `yourString.replace("\\\"", "")`

Comment: I want to catch everything between the \" at the start of the string and the \" at the end of the string. This is part of a much larger regex and a much larger string.

Comment: Escapes don't exist in the wild. They escape things. The rule is, in order to escape things the escape is escapable. That's just the way it is. If you think this is not true, then don't match the escape from your string. If it is true, then you don't know if something is escaped unless you test it. Escaped: `(?<\\)(?:\\\\)*\\(?!\\)`, Not Escaped: `(?<\\)(?:\\\\)*(?!\\)` where you substitute `(?!\\)` with the character to test.

Comment: This `\\"(?!\\ ` is not a valid regex. `The start of the regex is working` How do you know that? Show the code/work you did to find that out.

Comment: Doesn't `(?<=\\")(.*?)(?=\\")` work ? almost similar to @trincot answer

Comment: Seems the Asker has disappeared... After 22 hours and several comments, no sign of life.

Comment: I am alive. I responded to another comment that a answer fixed my problem. Infact it was your answer Trincot. My reply seems to have disappeared.